# GWT Code Server not finding a module in a newly generated project using a maven archetype

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt

I've worked with GWT and eclipse for a while now and I wanted to play a bit with maven and the GWT plugin (gwt-maven-plugin, [enter link description here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/)). I tried to use it out of eclipse (Luna 4.4), but obviously I didn't do it correctly, as it was extremely brittle to the point that it broke on a regular basis as the IDE overwrote it's settings when I changed something small in the pom.xml. So I decided to take a step back and eliminate the black magic that eclipse is and start a new project from scratch from the command line.

However, I cannot seem to be getting the hang of running the actual application, because when I execute the code server, navigate to the page, I see the following message:

```
Can't find any GWT Modules on this page.
```

Obviously, the code server is running, however the module files seem to not have been hosted. AFAIK I see after several hours of educating myself (and finding http://blog.ltgt.net/how-does-gwts-super-dev-mode-work/), there should be a second process actually hosting the code in parallel to the code server. What is the appropriate way of doing this with maven? Should I open a second terminal and run a jetty or something else in parallel to the code server? If so, could someone please give me a hint how I can do it most efficiently?

Thanks in advance!

Here is how I created the project:

```bash
mvn archetype:generate \
   -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo \
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=gwt-maven-plugin \
   -DarchetypeVersion=2.7.0
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[INFO] Archetype repository missing. Using the one from [org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0] found in catalog remote
Define value for property 'groupId': : com.mytest
Define value for property 'artifactId': : gwtmvntest
Define value for property 'version':  1.0-SNAPSHOT: :
Define value for property 'package':  com.mytest: : com.mytest.gwtmvntest
Define value for property 'module': : GwtMvnTest
Confirm properties configuration:
groupId: com.mytest
artifactId: gwtmvntest
version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
package: com.mytest.gwtmvntest
module: GwtMvnTest
 Y: :
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Archetype: gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: com.mytest
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: gwtmvntest
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: com.mytest.gwtmvntest
[INFO] Parameter: packageInPathFormat, Value: com/mytest/gwtmvntest
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: com.mytest.gwtmvntest
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Parameter: module, Value: GwtMvnTest
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: com.mytest
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: gwtmvntest
[INFO] project created from Archetype in dir: /private/tmp/mvn/gwtmvntest
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 08:12 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-14T12:59:17+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/310M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is how I compiled the project:

```bash
mvn compile gwt:compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building GWT Maven Archetype 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:generateAsync (default) @ gwtmvntest ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ gwtmvntest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ gwtmvntest ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 6 source files to /private/tmp/mvn/gwtmvntest/target/gwtmvntest-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:compile (default-cli) @ gwtmvntest ---
[INFO] Compiling module com.mytest.gwtmvntest.GwtMvnTest
[INFO]    Compiling 5 permutations
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 0...
[INFO]       Process output
[INFO]          Compiling
[INFO]             Compiling permutation 4...
[INFO]       Process output
[INFO]          Compiling
[INFO]             Compiling permutation 3...
[INFO]       Process output
[INFO]          Compiling
[INFO]             Compiling permutation 2...
[INFO]       Process output
[INFO]          Compiling
[INFO]             Compiling permutation 1...
[INFO]    Compile of permutations succeeded
[INFO]    Compilation succeeded -- 13.866s
[INFO] Linking into /private/tmp/mvn/gwtmvntest/target/gwtmvntest-1.0-SNAPSHOT/GwtMvnTest
[INFO]    Link succeeded
[INFO]    Linking succeeded -- 0.171s
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18.228 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-14T13:07:07+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/310M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is how I ran the project:

```bash
mvn gwt:run-codeserver
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building GWT Maven Archetype 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:run-codeserver (default-cli) > process-classes @ gwtmvntest >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:generateAsync (default) @ gwtmvntest ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ gwtmvntest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ gwtmvntest ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:run-codeserver (default-cli) < process-classes @ gwtmvntest <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:run-codeserver (default-cli) @ gwtmvntest ---
[INFO] Turning off precompile in incremental mode.
[INFO] Super Dev Mode starting up
[INFO]    workDir: /var/folders/nk/58gyq85x7l3_mzb5rc0gw42w0000gn/T/gwt-codeserver-5859907708379954718.tmp
[INFO]    Loading Java files in com.mytest.gwtmvntest.GwtMvnTest.
[INFO]    Module setup completed in 11742 ms
[ERROR] 2015-01-14 13:14:35.800:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] 2015-01-14 13:14:35.833:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:9876
[INFO]
[INFO] The code server is ready at http://localhost:9876/
```

Comment: You still need to deploy your application. The GWT code server allows you to recompile GWT code as needed in your application (it replaces all the JS code, IIRC), but the base application itself also needs to be running. In other words, deploy a test environment as you normally would, then start up the code server.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is there a way to do this in maven? I tried `mvn tomcat7:run` in a separate window. It delivers the HTML page at `http://localhost:8080/`, however there is still the message that says `Can't find any GWT Modules on this page.`

Comment: I checked the html that got served by the tomcat. It refers to `GwtMvnTest/GwtMvnTest.nocache.js`, ergo it tries to find it under `http://localhost:8080/`, where it isn't. It is under `http://localhost:9876/`, where it is served by the Code Server. Any ideas?

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/` won't load the script from `http://localhost:9876/` until after you run the `Dev Mode On` bookmarklet. That said, things are much easier since GWT 2.7; see my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With GWT 2.7+ all you need is to launch `mvn gwt:run` and it'll use SuperDevMode under the cover, with "recompile on load" (instead of using bookmarklets).
Note that `gwt:run` won't copy your `src/main/webapp` or your dependencies, so you'll likely have to run `mvn war:exploded` (or `mvn package`) as a prerequisite (and every time you change a file in `src/main/webapp` or you need to refresh your dependencies)

That being said, unless your project is really simple, you should start using distinct Maven modules early for client and server code; this is because Maven insists that you cannot manage a "GWT client-side classpath" and a "server-side classpath" in the same POM.
I published archetypes to help setting everything up: https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes (I unfortunately haven't had the time yet to update them to GWT 2.7)
Either that or use Gradle…

Comment: Thank you Thomas. The reason for the simple app is to eliminate as many variables as possible to find where the errors are. I like your modular-webapp archetype a lot and I will be definately looking at it after I fix the tooling. I tried your suggestion with the `mvn gwt:run` at first, however I wasn't able to see the suggested page. The "GWT Development Mode" starts, but opening the page `http://127.0.0.1:8888/GwtMvnTest.html` in the browser results in a 404 HTTP error. Would you be so kind and point me in the right direction, why the "GwtMvnTest.html" created by the archetype isn't served?

Comment: Ha, you have to run `mvn package` or `mvn war:exploded` (or whatever will copy your `src/main/webapp` to `target/gwtmvntest-1.0-SNAPSHOT` and your dependencies to `target/gwtmvntest-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib`) before you can use `mvn gwt:run`.

Comment: Hey Thomas, just tried the modular-webapp archetype from your github page. Simply created the app followed by `gwt:run` as you suggested. Results in the following: `The parameters 'runTarget' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0-rc1:run are missing or invalid`. Tried to change to gwt 2.7.0 in the top-level pom.xml to no avail. Same with GWT 2.7.0. I like the fact that the project is well distributed, but the tooling comes first... Am I missing something obvious, why the html files of the simpler app don't get recognized out of the box?

Comment: Thank you very much. The "mvn package" before "gwt:run" fix my issue. :)